# Close button on alert dosen´t work

Tags: template-framework

I´m triggering an alert by jQuery with Joomla.renderMessages.
The alert comes up, but won´t close when I press the close button!?

I´m using a custom template, I´ve made from scratch

I´ve search for answers without luck. according to this - https://docs.joomla.org/Display_error_messages_and_notices, it dosen´t seem like I need anything included in the template files, but I have the feeling that I need some javascript to make it work?

```
Joomla.renderMessages({'success': ['Du kan ikke gemme en tom note']});
```

Comment: Are you getting any console log errors?

Comment: @Lodder no, not at all

Comment: Can you share the full code you're using to render the alert in your question please?

Comment: Do I need to include 'media/jui/bootstrap.js' in my template?

Comment: @Lodder I´ve updated the question

Comment: Not directly. Instead use `JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework')`. And of course Bootstrap requires jQuery, so add this line before: `JHtml::_('jquery.framework')`

Comment: Ohhh, I feel stupid... adding those fixed it! thank you!!

Comment: @Lodder will you make this as an answer? :)

Comment: Sure, will do now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alerts derive from Bootstrap, therefore when developing a custom template, you need to make sure you include Bootstrap, and of course, jQuery.

You can do so by adding the following lines to your template's index.php file:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```